# SharedPreferences not saving, only default value

Tags: sharedpreferences

Im programming an android app in android studio. My ProfileView class extends the activity_profile_view.xml activity which allows the user to change their name and description. But everytime the methods onCreate or onResume is called, the default values are shown. No values that were supposed to be saved in onClick or onPause are ever shown. Thanks, this is my very first post.

```
public class ProfileView extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

public EditText NameEdit, AboutEdit;
public Button SaveButton;
public ImageButton NewPic;
public static final String Profile_Prefs = "Pro_File";
public static SharedPreferences profile;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_view);
   NameEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.NameEdit);
   AboutEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.AboutEdit);
   SaveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SaveButton);

   SaveButton.setOnClickListener(this);

  //Restore Preferences
   profile = this.getSharedPreferences(Profile_Prefs, 0);
   AboutEdit.setText(profile.getString("about", "About Me"));
   NameEdit.setText(profile.getString("name","name"));
}
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {

            SharedPreferences profile = getSharedPreferences(Profile_Prefs, 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = profile.edit();
            editor.putString(NameEdit.toString(),"name");
            editor.putString(AboutEdit.toString(),"about");
            editor.apply();
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(this, Main.class);
            startActivity(mainIntent);

};
@Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    SharedPreferences profile = getSharedPreferences(Profile_Prefs, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = profile.edit();
    editor.putString(NameEdit.toString(),"name");
    editor.putString(AboutEdit.toString(),"about");
    editor.commit();
}
@Override()
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    profile = this.getSharedPreferences(Profile_Prefs, 0);
    AboutEdit.setText(profile.getString("about", "About Me"));
    NameEdit.setText(profile.getString("name","name"));
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.profile_view, menu);
    return true;
}
```

After fixing onClick and onPause i get the fallowing in the editText fields in the app when onResume or onCreate is called.

> android.widget.EditText{1a0ea60cVFED..CL.F......32,263736,426#7f0a0003 app:id/NameEdit}
>   android.widget.EditText{651555eVFED..CL........92456-676,796#7f0a0009 app:id/AboutEdit}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that in the `OnClick()` method you need to change this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

        SharedPreferences profile = getSharedPreferences(Profile_Prefs, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = profile.edit();
        editor.putString(NameEdit.toString(),"name");
        editor.putString(AboutEdit.toString(),"about");
        editor.apply();
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(this, Main.class);
        startActivity(mainIntent);

};
```

with this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

        SharedPreferences profile = getSharedPreferences(Profile_Prefs, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = profile.edit();
        editor.putString("name",NameEdit.getText().toString()); //HERE I THINK YOU INVERTED KEY,VALUE ORDER, THIS IS THE CORRECT WAY
        editor.putString("about",AboutEdit.getText().toString()); //INVERTED KEY,VALUE ORDER HERE TOO
        editor.apply();
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(this, Main.class);
        startActivity(mainIntent);
};
```

Hope this helps

**EDIT:** I didn't notice but you have the same in onPause() method:

```
@Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    SharedPreferences profile = getSharedPreferences(Profile_Prefs, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = profile.edit();
    editor.putString("name",NameEdit.getText().toString()); //I THINK THIS IS THE CORRECT WAY
    editor.putString("about",AboutEdit.getText().toString()); //I THINK THIS IS THE CORRECT WAY
    editor.commit();
}
```

Comment: I think that helped, but now i have new feedback i don't understand. I updated my question with the new information.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to add `NameEdit.getText().toString()`. See my edited answer